# PHP 7 - Unsupported declare 'strict_types'

Tags: php, apache, type-hinting

Im using PHP 7 for a small project, also using same configs in my local and production server. all works on my local server but on production server after doing the set up for LAMP i was unable to find the apache folder under /etc/php/7.0/apache, so what i was getting an internal server error so i added the in apache.conf

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
PHPINIDir /path/to/new/php_ini
</VirtualHost>
```

Then the internal server error disappeared and now im getting this:

```
Warning: Unsupported declare 'strict_types' in /var/www/html/index.php on line 2
```

Any idea why!!
Thanks in advance

Comment: What does `php -v` return in your production server?

Comment: @apokryfos this is what i get PHP 7.0.3-13+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) ( NTS )

Comment: Create a simple page on your apache http root with the line : <?php phpinfo(); to make sure your apache is using the correct PHP module.

Answer (score 8):

in laravel 5.8 i install PHP version 7.2 and worked

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to use Composer whilst figuring out this error: Composer showed that I needed ext-mbstring. I then ran:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring
```

And everything worked, even the main error was gone:

```
"Warning: Unsupported declare 'strict_types' in /var/www/html/index.php on line 2
"
```

I can only assume that missing extensions cause other unexpected errors.

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded PHP from 7.4 to 7.3 using  MultiPHP Manager tool in cPanel and it worked.