# Error in Laravel vendor files: Warning: Unsupported declare 'strict_types' in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, php-7

For some reason on my Laravel 5.3 application when I run composer update I get the following error

> Warning: Unsupported declare 'strict_types' in
>   /home/site/public_html/bookings/vendor/league/csv/src/functions.php
>   on line 13

I think it may have to do with the PHP Version as its not recognizing the PHP 7 typing constructs, I am running PHP 7.0.25 on my server however when I run `php -v` in my console when I ssh into the server it shows PHP 5.6.32.

Anyone have any idea why its moaning about this core file? I have not touched any of the files in the vendor folder.

Here is the contents of that file:

```
<?php
/**
* This file is part of the League.csv library
*
* @license http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
* @link https://github.com/thephpleague/csv/
* @version 9.1.1
* @package League.csv
*
* For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
* file that was distributed with this source code.
*/
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace League\Csv;

use ReflectionClass;
use Traversable;

/**
 * Returns the BOM sequence found at the start of the string
 *
 * If no valid BOM sequence is found an empty string is returned
 *
 * @param string $str
 *
 * @return string
 */
function bom_match(string $str): string
{
    static $list;

    $list = $list ?? (new ReflectionClass(ByteSequence::class))->getConstants();

    foreach ($list as $sequence) {
        if (0 === strpos($str, $sequence)) {
            return $sequence;
        }
    }

    return '';
}

/**
 * Detect Delimiters usage in a {@link Reader} object
 *
 * Returns a associative array where each key represents
 * a submitted delimiter and each value the number CSV fields found
 * when processing at most $limit CSV records with the given delimiter
 *
 * @param Reader   $csv        the CSV object
 * @param string[] $delimiters list of delimiters to consider
 * @param int      $limit      Detection is made using up to $limit records
 *
 * @return int[]
 */
function delimiter_detect(Reader $csv, array $delimiters, int $limit = 1): array
{
    $found = array_unique(array_filter($delimiters, function (string $value): bool {
        return 1 == strlen($value);
    }));
    $stmt = (new Statement())->limit($limit)->where(function (array $record): bool {
        return count($record) > 1;
    });
    $reducer = function (array $result, string $delimiter) use ($csv, $stmt): array {
        $result[$delimiter] = count(iterator_to_array($stmt->process($csv->setDelimiter($delimiter)), false), COUNT_RECURSIVE);

        return $result;
    };
    $delimiter = $csv->getDelimiter();
    $header_offset = $csv->getHeaderOffset();
    $csv->setHeaderOffset(null);
    $stats = array_reduce($found, $reducer, array_fill_keys($delimiters, 0));
    $csv->setHeaderOffset($header_offset)->setDelimiter($delimiter);

    return $stats;
}

if (!function_exists('\is_iterable')) {
    /**
     * Tell whether the content of the variable is iterable
     *
     * @see http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-iterable.php
     *
     * @param mixed $iterable
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    function is_iterable($iterable): bool
    {
        return is_array($iterable) || $iterable instanceof Traversable;
    }
}

/**
 * Tell whether the content of the variable is an int or null
 *
 * @see https://wiki.php.net/rfc/nullable_types
 *
 * @param mixed $value
 *
 * @return bool
 */
function is_nullable_int($value): bool
{
    return null === $value || is_int($value);
}
```

Comment: See: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35746444/php-7-unsupported-declare-strict-types  it unfortunately doesn't have a checked answer but the OP answered it themself. the gist is make sure `mbstring` is installed.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Yeah that question has no accepted answer, plus this question is specific to Laravel as the error takes place in a Laravel package.

Comment: It's a  PHP error just because it happens in Lavavel doesn't mean is a Lavavel only thing.  create a separate PHP file outside of your project with that in it and see what happens.

Comment: Regardless, that question doesn't help.

Comment: Do you have the `mbstring` extension installed?  I'm not saying that's the correct answer but ...  Personally I don't see any reason for strict typing on a web application, well non but frustration.

Comment: Not sure as I can't even run sudo commands, running this on a shared server was a BIG mistake.

Comment: you can do phpinfo() and see if it's listed, no>?  http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php  or you could try using one of the `mb_` string functions, like `mb_strpos($str, $string)` and it will blow up if it's not installed.  `mb` is the multi byte string functions `PHP6` was supposed to fix, tell it blew up.

Answer (score 2):

Your servers web has PHP 7 enabled (if you took it from phpinfo();), but CLI of your server doesn't. The command you are trying to run is being run from console.

CLI and WEB PHP versions are differn't things.

If your server is Debian based (Ubuntu).
Look into /etc/php and see if there are multiple PHP versions, if there are, you can make symbolic link to link your CLI version also to PHP 7

```
sudo ln -sfn /usr/bin/php7.0 /usr/bin/php
```